# What is the most efficient way to implement a cron job to back up a MySQL database and e-mail it to myself?

Tags: backup, ftp, mysql, mysqldump

What would be the most efficient way to automatically back up a MySQL Database, gzip it, and e-mail it to a specific account?

I am a bit paranoid about losing my forum's database and I'm usually busy during the week and often forget to do a weekly backup (instead, doing bi-weekly, or monthly, which isn't too bad, but less frequent than I'd like). Having it set up with a cronjob and an e-mail (or FTP/SFTP as I've just realized one of the databases would be too large to attach in an e-mail) would be a lot easier, as well as less prone to me forgetting.

How I'm looking at it now would be:

mysqldump dbname > YYYY-MM-DD_dbname.sql
gzip YYYY-MM-DD_dbname.sql
Either send YYYY-MM-DD_dbname.sql.gz as an attachment to an e-mail address or {S,}FTP it to another server and send an e-mail letting me know that the backup and transfer was successful.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Any examples of how you'd accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do much better than what you've got. I'd probably use something like the following:

- create the database dump
- gzip it or otherwise compress it (technically optional)
- use `scp` or `rsync` to copy the file to another server
- run a checksum on the remote server to verify the copy (optional)
- delete the original database dump (optional)
- send an email indicating success

Or if any step of this fails, quit and immediately send an email explaining the failure. (I'm assuming you have the necessary tools available, e.g. `rsync` or `scp`, `sha1sum` or `md5sum`, `gzip`, `mail` or `sendmail` or equivalent)

Comment: I wouldn't mark the checksum part as optional. The day the db crashes and you're all happy because you have a recent backup, only to find out it was corrupted is not something I would like to experience.

In addition, I'd probably use xz instead of gzip, only because the resulting file is smaller in size.

Comment: @tamtakos: if you skip the checksum step, as long as nothing goes wrong with the other steps, the database dump will be transferred. That makes it optional. (As opposed to, say, the `scp` step which cannot be omitted) What I think you mean to say is that the checksum should be highly recommended, and with that I agree.